# Access query: Like statement containing a today method

Tags: mysql, ms-access

I currently have a Access query containing USERID, CHECKTIME, VERIFYCODE, SSN and Name.

CHECKTIME's value consists of a date and time ("2016/01/20 10:34:38 AM").

Under Design View I would like to change the criteria for that column to use a like statement combined with a Now() method. I want the query to only show values where the column CHECKTIME's value is LIKE Today's date.

***EDIT***

I have changed the Access SQL View code to this:

CHECKINOUT.CHECKTIME Like (Now() + '*')

But now I'm getting Data type mismatch in criteria expression!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is a query in Access, then use this Access SQL:

```
Select * From CHECKINOUT Where DateValue([CHECKTIME]) = Date()
```

Comment: I am looking for something like this: CHECKINOUT.CHECKTIME Like =Today()% It must get everything that starts with today's date

Comment: Scratch my last comment, it works now! XD Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0):

why you dont use mysql date() function?
for example:
select date(a) from A;

> > 2015-01-26
> >     "a" column format is : 2015-01-26 12:13:23

Comment: Not the problem I'm facing. I need to use a Like statement with a =Today() method. It must look something like this: Like =Today()%. I want all the values that START with today's date.